# Fetch lookup column data in excel using ODATA Feed from SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, excel

I am trying to fetch a data from SharePoint list to excel. **Lookup column with multiple choice (person and group field)** is not getting populated in the excel. Can anyone help me with this. Below is my REST endpoint uri being used

```
<site name>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$expand=Owner&$select=Owner/Title
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your lookupcolumn internal name?

Comment: Owner is internal name

Comment: Is that a lookup column or people or group column?

Comment: lookup column with multiple selection

Comment: Kindly refer this.....http://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html

Comment: @Hardik if you seen in URL have done same, but not able to fetch a data from SharePoint list.

Comment: Can you try to change it to `<site name>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=Owner/Title&$expand=Owner` ?

Comment: Do you just want to export the SP list data to excel??

Comment: @Hardik yes. i want to fetch data from SharePoint list to Excel 2013 using OData feed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41435/discussion-between-hardik-and-rahul-dayal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of reasons mentioned in below article by which your query will not work & will not fetch the data from SharePoint List columns.

**One of the example given in below article is**

> Well if you know SharePoint lists, you know you can change field
>   display names, and many other things in List Settings. In the screen
>   shot above, the “Affiliation” columns are columns which are lookups to
>   the Accounts list. I renamed the column name in the Customers list to
>   be “Affiliate”. This is an important point to remember. The “entity”
>   you are referencing here is the “Affiliation” entity, not the
>   “Accounts” entity.  If I call the Account Lookup field “Affiliate” and
>   link by Id, then project the Name and AccountId columns I have to use
>   the following to get the AffiliationId back.

Kindly check below article for **OData $expand Query Option**.

[Using the $expand OData Query Option in SharePoint 2013](http://www.threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/)

**Alternate option to get SharePoint list data to excel**

You can use **Power Query** to fetch SharePoint Online List data to Excel.

With this tool, a lot of different sources can be extracted into Excel with just a few clicks. This tip will show you how you can read a SharePoint list with Power Query and how you can extract its contents into Excel.

Kindly check below article for further details.

[Extracting a SharePoint List with Power Query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3625/extracting-a-sharepoint-list-with-power-query/)

[How to Use Power Query for Excel to Query a SharePoint 2013 List](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/08/22/how-to-use-power-query-for-excel-to-query-a-sharepoint-2013-list-aspx/)

Comment: power query option looks good but there is no option for fetching a data from SharePoint List as shown in above blog entry

Comment: Do you have this installed? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Comment: yes.. same version

Comment: I have added one link... Kindly check it how to use Power query.

Comment: Did you tried it? Is it working for you?

Comment: the option from get data from SharePoint list is not visible in Power Query

Comment: can you please provide the screen capture of the same? as it is simple & mentioned on MSDN as well...https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-SharePoint-List-Power-Query-3226f248-f8b3-4777-82ce-b4ed04dedaaf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41441/discussion-between-hardik-and-rahul-dayal).

Answer (score 0):

Try this endpoint URL to get the Multi Choice Lookup field data:

```
var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Product Type')/items?$select=Owner/Title&$expand=Owner/ID";
```

To retrieve the data of each values of multiple field use below code,

```
var items = data.d.results;
var owners;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    owners = items[i].Owner.results;
    for (var j = 0; j < owners.length; j++) {
        alert(owners[j].Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: below answer doesn't help for me, as i want to fetch data from sharepoint list to excel 2013.